# Data Type not understood in tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, neural-network, deeplearning4j

```
mean , variance = tf.nn.moments(X_train, axes = 1, keep_dims = True)
```

I am trying to get the mean and variance using `tf.nn.moments()` as shown above. However, I am encountering the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-fc383f99b15b> in <module>()
     33 Y_train = Y_train.reshape(1,355)
     34 X_mean = tf.reduce_mean(X_train, axis = 1, keepdims = True)
---> 35 mean , variance = tf.nn.moments(X_train, axes = 1, keep_dims = True)
     36 X_train = tf.divide(tf.subtract(X_train,mean),tf.sqrt(variance))
     37 #Y_train = Y_train/(Y_train.max(axis = 1, keepdims = True))

/Users/abhinandanchiney/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-      packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.pyc in moments(x, axes, shift, name, keep_dims)
    664     # sufficient statistics. As a workaround we simply perform the operations
    665     # on 32-bit floats before converting the mean and variance back to fp16
--> 666     y = math_ops.cast(x, dtypes.float32) if x.dtype == dtypes.float16 else x
    667     # Compute true mean while keeping the dims for proper broadcasting.
    668     mean = math_ops.reduce_mean(y, axes, keepdims=True, name="mean")

 TypeError: data type not understood
```

Kindly help where I am going wrong.

Comment: Post the definition of `X_train`

Comment: @Maxim X_train = np.array([[....],[....]....[...]]), it is a 30x355 numpy array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`tf.nn.moments`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/moments) is expecting a tensor, not a numpy array:

> Args:
>
> - `x`: A Tensor.

Try this:

```py
x = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_train)
mean , variance = tf.nn.moments(x, axes = 1, keep_dims = True)
```

Comment: It did helped in removing the error about incorrect data, but now has thrown up a new error which is due to the fact  that I cannot pass "x" to a function. 







`---> 96 parameters = model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test)
     

in model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, learning_rate, num_epochs, print_cost)
---> 73             _ , minibatch_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: X_train, Y: Y_train})
     

TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.`

Comment: @Abhinandan this looks like another problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/42560209/712995 or feel free to ask a new question.